# Divisibility of number $s\perp 10$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I found a property that for $s\perp 10$ we can say that there exists such $k$ that
$$
10^k \equiv 1 \pmod s
$$
but I cannot prove it. Can you help me in this task.

**My approach:**

When $s\perp 10$ then we know that there exists such $x,y$ that $10x+sy=1$. So we can state that $10x\equiv1 \;\;(mod\;s)$. But I don't know what do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be naturals with $a\perp b$. Consider the infinite sequence 
$$a\bmod b,\ a^2\bmod b,\ a^3\bmod b,\ \ldots$$
As only $b$ distinct values are possible, some repetition must occur, i.e.,  we can find naturals $1\le i<j$ such that $a^i\equiv a^j\pmod b$. Then  with $k:=j-i>0$, we have $a^i\equiv a^ia^k\pmod b$. As $a\perp b$, this implies $1\equiv a^k\pmod b$.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Euler’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem), such $k$ exists and $k=\varphi(s)$.